# Why is there no immediate increment when i++ is defined as the increment in for loop whereas it's reflected in the case of an if statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm just a beginner at C++ and I came across this instance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int c = 3;
  int d = c++;
  if (c++ == 4 && d == 3)
    cout << "1: " << c << " " << d << endl;
  if (++c == 5 && d-- == 3)
    cout << "2: " << c-- << " " << d << endl;
  cout << "3: " << c << " " << d << endl;
}
```

So in this case, the output would be:

```
1: 5 3
3: 6 3
```

And what I understand from this is that the variables would still be updated even if they are being called for an increment in the if statement.

Now I came across this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std:
int main(){
   for (int i= 1; i <= 10; ++i){
     cout << i ;
     break
   }
}
```

And even though its being incremented it's only returning 1. So I thought that maybe the 2nd time  it goes through the loop (after removing the break of course) it would return 3, cause then it would have passed through ++i twice, but it's still 2. I don't understand.  So my question is why would there be an instant increment in the if statement but there is none when ++i exists in the for loop ?

EDIT: just fixed a typo. I was supposed to type semicolon but put a comma instead :b

EDIT: added a more straightforward question as some are wondering what I am asking.

Comment: i <= 10,  is this line correctly copied e.g. did you mean to have a comma there?

Comment: You can analyze your code with: https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgp1c2luZyBuYW1lc3BhY2Ugc3RkOwppbnQgbWFpbigpewogICBmb3IgKGludCBpID0gMTsgaSA8PSAxMDsgKytpKXsKICAgICBjb3V0IDw8IGkgOwogICAgIGJyZWFrOwogICB9Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp17,alt-syntax-for&std=cpp17&rev=1.0. You will find out that the increment is applied after the first iteration, not before

Comment: `for (int i= 1; i <= 10, ++i)` has typo and should be `for (int i= 1; i <= 10; ++i)`

Comment: @TheKingSid I have understood nothing. What is the question?

Comment: Even it may be nice for understanding, but you should NEVER use such code with that use of pre & post increments in assignments at all. It not readable and as this dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A for statement has 4 parts, they are not in the order they are executed.

```
for ( init-statement condition; iteration_expression) statement
```

Is [defined as equivalent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) to

```
{
    init_statement
    while ( condition ) {
        statement
        iteration_expression ;
    }
}
```

Except that

1. Names declared by the *init-statement* (if *init-statement* is a declaration) and names declared by *condition* (if *condition* is a declaration) are in the same scope (which is also the scope of *statement*).
2. `continue` in the statement will execute *iteration_expression*
3. Empty *condition* is equivalent to `while(true)`

Comment: Semicolon is missing.

Comment: @user207421 no, semicolon is always a part of *init_statement*, and *statement* might (should) be wrapped in `{}`